# spray app on Heroku: not able to find script created from stage command

Tags: bash, scala, heroku, spray

trying my hand at spray/scala for the first time and I am stuck with a deploy error on Heroku

here's the contents for target directory locally after `sbt clean compile stage` ran successfully

```
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:mail-service anadi$ cd target/universal/stage/bin/
Anadis-MacBook-Pro:bin anadi$ ls -ltr
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 anadi  staff   4877 Feb  3 19:10 mail-service.bat
-rwxr--r--  1 anadi  staff  10973 Feb  3 19:10 mail-service
```

& I am able to launch the spray app, cloned from [spray-github](https://github.com/spray/spray-template), locally

```
19:18:14 web.1  | started with pid 46761
19:18:20 web.1  | [INFO] [02/03/2015 19:18:20.367] [on-spray-can-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://on-spray-can/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

but it fails on Heroku

```
2015-02-03T13:46:07.695518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/mail-service`
2015-02-03T13:46:09.308482+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/universal/stage/bin/mail-service: No such file or directory
```

***Update***

ran `heroic run bash` as suggested by @n1r3

```
heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3163
~ $ pwd
/app
~ $ ls -ltr
total 32
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873   23 Feb  3 13:41 system.properties
drwx------ 4 u57873 57873 4096 Feb  3 13:41 src
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873  657 Feb  3 13:41 build.sbt
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873  317 Feb  3 13:41 UPDATING.md
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873 1581 Feb  3 13:41 README.markdown
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873   45 Feb  3 13:41 Procfile
drwx------ 4 u57873 57873 4096 Feb  3 13:42 project
drwx------ 4 u57873 57873 4096 Feb  3 13:45 target

~ $ ls -ltr target/universal/stage/     
total 8
drwx------ 2 u57873 57873 4096 Feb  3 13:44 lib
drwx------ 2 u57873 57873 4096 Feb  3 13:44 bin

~ $ ls -ltr target/universal/stage/bin/
total 20
-rw------- 1 u57873 57873  5020 Feb  3 13:44 scala_buildpack_build_dir.bat
-rwx------ 1 u57873 57873 10986 Feb  3 13:44 scala_buildpack_build_dir
```

So the script is named scala_buildpack_build_dir, while Heroku expects a script named mail_service. Anything I am missing in the configuration?

Comment: What is your `Procfile` ?

Comment: `web: target/universal/stage/bin/mail-service`

Comment: Have you tried doing a `heroku run bash` and then trying to find out what you actually deployed ?

Comment: Nice to know about it :-P ....

Comment: I have added to the question what I saw from the Heroku bash terminal, usually stage is supposed to create a script with the project name, could it be because `name` setting is missing in my `build.sbt` file?

Comment: added `name:=mail-service` and pushed to Heroku it works fine now.

Comment: I see, glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the name= in the build.sbt file.

I have been struggling with a new Spray-can/spray/akka app in Heroku too, and found that most of the documentation is a jumble of historical info.

I now have my app deployed OK (finally!).  I am using:

- sbt 0.13.6,
- scala 2.10.4,
- sbt-native-packager 1.0.0-M4
- git 1.9.5
- Heroku toolbelt 3.25.0
- Java 1.8

In your project/plugins.sbt you want:

> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-M4")

In project/build.properties:

> sbt.version=0.13.6

In your root build.sbt you want, as well as the normal stuff:

> name := "myserver"
>   enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

Don't be tempted to use enablePlugins(AkkaAppPackaging) - it generates a very different shell script and you'll get a 'akka main class' not found error.

In the root Procfile:

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/myserver

Just to clarify, this Procfile means "run the shell script target/universal/stage/bin/myserver to start my web server".  If you run "sbt compile stage" locally you can view a copy of the script locally.  You can also use bash, as above, to see the version generated on the Heroku server.

The 1.0 sbt native packager seems to find your web server entry point automatically and put it as a default into the shell file, hence you don't need add it onto the end of the Procfile.  i.e. you **don't** need:

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/myserver web.Main

Comment: Thanks Herc. I had all of things in place except `name` got it to work after I added that.

Comment: What Spray-can/spray/akka docs on Heroku did you find that were out of date? I'd love to update them if I can.

Comment: joekutner - i was working form https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support mainly, but that seems to be have been updated a couple of days ago, and I think web: target looks much better now (thanks).  However does that format work on packager on 0.8.0?  It might be better to recommend 1.0.0?